# Tkinter - How to get Keypress anywhere on window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, keypress

I am trying to get keypresses in Python (2.7.10), bit I had no luck with `getch()`, as `ord(getch())` was returning 255 constantly, so I am now using Tkinter. *(I believe that Tkinter is also cross-platform so that should help as i plan to run this script on a Linux device).*

I need to be able to get keypresses, even if they are not pressed while the Tkinter window is not active.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time, threading

x = "Hi!"

def callback(event):
    x = "key: " + event.char
    print(x)

def doTk():
    root = Tk()
    root.bind_all("<Key>", callback)
    root.withdraw()
    root.mainloop()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=doTk)
thread1.deamon = True
thread1.start()
```

I am not reveiving any errors, it is not not registering keypresses. I have also tried this without using threading, but it still does not work.

Please also note that I cannot use `raw_input()` as I need this to be able to run in the background and still get keypresses.

*I am aware that this does not produce a frame, I do not want it to.*

Thanks in advance for any help :)

PS: I have looked to other answers on StackOverflow and other sites, but they all either don't work or give solutions where keypresses are only registered when the tkinter frame is active.

Comment: Tkinter will only see events when it is active and has the keyboard focus.

Comment: @BryanOakley so there is no possible way to get keypress events from anywhere on a window?

If not, can you suggest another method of getting keypress events without using `getch`?

Comment: have you looked into pyHook https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook

Comment: @user2682863 pyHook is not cross-platform, isn't it?

Comment: Correct: there is no cross-platform way for tkinter to get keyboard events if it doesn't have the keyboard focus, and it can't get the keyboard focus if it's not the active window.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, is there a low-leval API that works with Linux and I'll use that with pyHook and a helper function.

Comment: Is it important for you to use tkinter?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That was me being stupid, not indenting.

Comment: It wasn't too important for me to use Tkinter, do you have an alternative?